# Insert Tracepoint: how to set the default message?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, trace, breakpoints

In MS VisualStudio (I'm using 2005), it's possible to right-click in some code file and 'insert tracepoint' right there.

The default message printed when the tracepoint is hit is `Function: $FUNCTION, Thread: $TID $TNAME`.  I would rather have it different (e.g. `Thread: $TID [{(void*)this}::$FUNCTION]`).  Now it's easy to just type in the required message, but I don't want to do that for the rest of my career.

How do I set the default tracepoint message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the registry and alter the value of the key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Debugger\DefaultTracepointMessage.

Comment: Thanks!  (How do you know these things?)